# finding list by expresion

Tags: functions

Well Im new to mathematica. I have list of x which contain {1,23,45,6,43}.
And I get expression from

```
g = Fit[t, {1, v, v^2}, v]
```

how can apply list x to g to receive list of answers y

Comment: If your list is saved as `x`, then you could try `Table[g, {v, x}]`.